# join query works in console but not in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I asked a previous question about how to properly structure my search query, but I find that it only works in console. What I have here is virtually identical to a search method used on another model (the other doesn't use joins), but for some reason this one returns nothing. This one also spits `%5B%5D` out into the url, whereas the other does not.

The search function in my model:

```
Class Collection
 def self.search(search)
  if search
   joins(blob: :item).where("items.a ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  else
   order('id DESC')
  end
 end
end
```

My controller:

```
@collections = if params[:search]
 current_user.collections.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
else
 current_user.collections.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

And my view:

```
<%= form_tag collections_path, method: 'get' do %>
 <%= text_field :search, params[:search] %>
<% end %>

<% @collections.each do |c| %>
 <%= c.item.a %>
 blah blah
<% end %>
```

The terminal output I get is

> `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "collections" INNER
>   JOIN "blobs" ON "blobs"."id" = "collections"."blob_id" INNER JOIN
>   "items" ON "items"."id" = "blobs"."item_id" WHERE
>   "collections"."user_id" = $1 AND (items.a ILIKE '%#{search}%') 
>   [["user_id", 1]].

Really seems like this should be working, but it's not?

Comment: From about log, The search keyword is not replacing with the original value coming from parameter.

Comment: did you try with `left_outer_join` ?

Comment: @Vishal the issue isn't the sql. the sql works, but the search implementation does not. i'm not able to determine why.

Comment: @sabaeus if its working fine in your rails console, then it should also work for controller action or model method. try to debug code, that's the only way, because on basis of this code we can't judge any more

Answer (score 4):

Here is in the OP seeing some wrong, so the follow to the below.

> In the join query, no any issue, the issue is where `view` & `controller`

You don't need the `if search` condition because you have already this into controller method

```
def self.search(search)
    joins(blob: :item).where("items.a ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

Look the `ILIKE` key only work for PostgreSQL, if your development database is `sqlite3` then the query will look like this otherwise as is

```
joins(blob: :item).where("lower(items.a) LIKE (?)", "%#{search.downcase}%")
```

change this into `self.search` method.

And into the controller follow this code

```
if params[:search].present?
    @collections = current_user.collections.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
else
    @collections = current_user.collections.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

And text field change like this

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, value: params[:search] %>
```

So the form will look like this

```
<%= form_tag collections_path, method: 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it will work.